# If user input a value that doesn't exist on database it will set text label with MySQL using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What's the exact query for that? The best that I was able to come up with is setting the TextLabel message if what the user input is blank, but not if what the user inputted is wrong. I don't know the right query for it. I tried NULL but I don't know the exact query for it so I tried = Nothing and it did Nothing. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim connString As String = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=cph;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT emp_firstnm, emp_midnm, emp_lastnm FROM employee_table WHERE emp_no = @empno"

    If txtEmpno.Text = Nothing Then
        Label4.Text = "No such employee exists"
    Else

        Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
            Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()
                With sqlComm
                    .Connection = sqlConn
                    .CommandText = sqlQuery
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", txtEmpno.Text)
                End With
                Try
                    sqlConn.Open()
                    Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
                    While sqlReader.Read()
                        Label4.Text = sqlReader("emp_firstnm").ToString() & " " & sqlReader("emp_midnm").ToString() & " " & sqlReader("emp_lastnm").ToString()
                    End While
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                Finally
                    sConnection.Dispose()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpno.Text)) Then
```

Or

```
If (txtEmpno.Text = String.Empty) Then
```

...which is the equivalent of

```
If (txtEmpno.Text = "") Then
```

A `String` is a reference type (class) and *can* be set to `Nothing`. But, by design, a label will always return an empty string `""`, not a null.

```
txtEmpno.Text = Nothing
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}, {1}", (txtEmpno.Text Is Nothing), (txtEmpno.Text = "")))
```

Will output:

```
False, True
```

Comment: It doesn't work man. I tried the IsNullOrEmpty query but it doesn't work. When the textbox is empty it outputs correctly but if I input the wrong number it doesn't. It's supposed to base on some values in the database.